# Input Validation with JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, validation, joptionpane

I'm doing input validation on a program using `JOptionPane` boxes. I'm trying to have the input box repeat after the error message every time the user enters in a non-double. How would I do this?

```
    try {
        lengthResult = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the length of your garage in square feet?"));
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a number in digit format.","Inane error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Comment: How about a do-while loop with condition of lengthResult filled?

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks for the input. I've played around with that notion and it's definitely the right way to go about validating input. I'm just not sure how to set the code up.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to repeat the message box until the user enters something valid, I'd go like this:

```
Double lengthResult = null; //Init to null, which is invalid
String title = "Please anter a number";
int initialType = JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE;
do {
  try {
    lengthResult = Double.parseDouble(
      JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
         "What is the length of your garage in square feet?",
         title, initialType));
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    initialType = JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE;
    title = "Error: Please enter a number!";
  }
} while(lengthResult == null); //Iterate as long as no valid input found
```

Note that this check relies on lengthResult being an Object of type Double, not a primitive type double. With primitive double you'd need some extra flag as you cannot check on lengthResult value this way.

Comment: Thanks Jan, this is making a lot more sense now. What I'm getting now are two errors, one on the line "Double lengthResult = null; and one on the last line "while (lengthResult ==null);. The first error says "cannot covert from null to double." Eclipse is telling me the operator is undefined for the argument types double, null for the second error. Any idea why?

Comment: You may have length result already defined as double (small d) instead of Double (capital D)?

Comment: Yes! That would be why. Thanks for all your help Jan, this made my program do exactly what I wanted. I'll read more into the different between "double" and "Double."